# WolframKernel not found when running WolframScript

Tags: scripting, command-line, interoperability

While attempting to run wolframscript in linux, I get the error

"WolframKernel not found. Use -configure to set WOLFRAMSCRIPT_KERNELPATH Or export WolframKernel=/yourpath/WolframKernel"

I am relatively new to the CL and am unsure what that means. When I run wolframscript from the directory that I made the symlink to the executable in, wolframscript works fine. I added this directory to my path,